# How do I use multiple queries in a query scope Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an array of "services" which I want to fetch them all in a query scope only if they have value (not null)

here is my code for fetching them:

```
public function scopeWithAllServices($query)
{
    return $query->with(['serviceA', 'serviceB', 'serviceC', 'serviceD']);
}
```

This code gives me all services even if they are null.

The question is, how do I use multiple queries in a query scope? like foreach services if service not null... and then return the query.

Comment: Did you try `return $query->has(['serviceA', 'serviceB', 'serviceC', 'serviceD']);`?

Comment: What I want is $query->has and $query->with together, by the way $query->has only accepts string, not array!

Comment: If the relationship doesn't exist, `with` will just set the relation to `null`. What's the problem?

Comment: @fubar I don't wan't it to be seen in my collection, because my API gets so much null values in it

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
$query->whereNotNull('serviceA', 'serviceB', 'serviceC', 'serviceD')
```

Comment: This is my question: How do I use multiple queries in a query scope Laravel